# Smooch support on ipv6 network

Tags: ipv6, smooch

I am currently using Smooch in my iOS application.
Everything works good during the implementation and test process. But the AppStore update has been rejected because of a crash when the user launches a new discussion with Smooch. The issue rises only when the device is connected to an ipv6 network (everything is OK on ipv4, 3G/4G). I might explore deeper in the API.

My question is :
Does smooch is ipv6 compliant?
Is there specific configuration to suppot it on the app?

Comment: Which version of the Smooch SDK are you using? There are a couple of crashes, one specifically happened starting a new convo, that were fixed in version 5.4.5

Comment: OK, thanks. We are currently under 5.2.1. I will make the update. More info from my side, i have tried to reproduce with ipv6 network (using nat64 internet shar ing from macOS), but everything is OK. I have to analyse crash report now. I will compare with the modification made on 5.4.5.

Comment: OK it appears that it's not linked to ipv6 (don't know why Apple suggested that). App is now on review with updated smooch lib, let's see.